# dompdf - display data from a SQL query

Tags: php, html, dompdf

How I can display the data in tr depending on the number of characters.

my code is:

```
<?php
$query = "select text from mytable where id=".$_POST["id"];

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);    
?>

<table>
<tr class="text-center border">
     <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr class="text-center border">
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="text-center border">
     <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if the text exceeds I want to show in the other row tr.

Comment: start with http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: I like the answer provided, simple and clean. If it doesn't work for you describe the layout you are trying to achieve rather than the HTML structure and maybe we can offer other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have a look at `str_split`

```
<table>
    <?php
        $parts = str_split($row[0], 20);
        foreach ($parts as $part):
    ?>
        <tr class="text-center border">
            <td><?php echo $part; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
</table>
```

This way you'll just slice your value into as many parts of your desired length (20 chars in my example) as it takes and output them into table rows in a loop.

Comment: thank you... It works, but how do I calculate the number of characters correctly.

Comment: Well I though you know how many chars per row you need (I set 20 just as a reference). If you do then you don't have to think about it. If it's less than that you'll get one row. If more they will get sliced into pieces 20 chars each and the last one will get what's left.

Comment: I have several items to display in this way in the PDF that I will generate and for all the rows I have to use a number of different chars. there any way to calculate maximum characters depending on the screen resolution?

Comment: I've done this in the past. The problem is that in modern fonts event the letters are not of the same width. "i" doesn't take up as much space as "u" so simple character count will not work. In my case it wasn't HTML to PDF conversion so I actually calculated the width of the string and sliced it based on that

Comment: the problem is that I use uppercase and lowercase and uppercase letters take up more space. $text = "TEXT:" .$row[0];    $parts = str_split($text, 20);

Comment: You might be able to do this using dompdf or the underlying CPDF backend to determine the text width. Once you have a document set up you can query CPDF for the width of a block of text based on the currently selected font. Widths are returned in pt units and PDF documents are fixed at 72 ppi. Of course, that doesn't really help much in the middle of a render since you don't necessarily know the width of the space you're working in. As I mentioned in my comment to your question it might help to know the layout you're trying to create (with variants indicating why this is important).

Comment: I was afraid you'd ask that ... I'll see if I can put something together.